# How to set environment variables under MATE?

Tags: environment-variables, desktop-environment, mate-desktop

I have just installed MATE under Ubuntu Saucy. No problems. Except I am trying to setup [Texmaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texmaker), the LaTeX IDE, and cannot figure out how to set the paths to the LaTeX tools (`pdflatex`, etc.) which Texmaker spawns.

Now I have used Texmaker for several years under Ubuntu Precise with Gnome fallback, and I know to set the path in `~/.gnomerc`. But I cannot find the equivalent of `~/.gnomerc` under Mate. (You would have thought `.materc` but it appears not.)

So how do I set environment variables under Mate?

Comment: Have you tried manually create $HOME/.gnomerc file and set your variables here? Previosly MATE have sourced that file just like GNOME. But I'm not sure if still works.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance here if MATE for whatever visionary reason replaces or bypasses use of the shell, but can't these be set the normal way (`.profile`, `.bashrc`, etc.)?

Comment: I'm with @goldilocks why don't you use the normal methods? Just add the relevant lines to your `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. In any case, `texmaker` should not need any variables, you can just give it the full path to the commands you need it to find.

Comment: Putting the environment variables in ~./bashrc does **not** work. Texmaker, which is a GUI program, is not descended from the bash shell but from the window manager(?). So the _normal_ method will not work.

Comment: I could add the full path to the commands. But I view this as a hack. Environment variables are provided for a very good purpose! What I am trying to do is possible under Gnome via ~/.gnomerc. What's the Mate equivalent given that it's fork of Gnome?

Comment: In response to diffycat, adding the environment variables in ~/.gnomerc does not work. Tried that already.

Answer (score 1):

I have (eventually) answered my own question! The solution is to add the `export PATH = ...` statement to a file (`*.sh`) in `/etc/profile.d`. This is executed when both the bash shell and window session manager start. And it applies for all users, unlike the `.gnomerc` solution in my original post.

See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables for further details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a generic place to add things like this: `~/.xsessionrc`.

This is on Ubuntu Trusty 14.04:

```
$ grep -rs USERXSESSIONRC /etc/
/etc/gdm/Xsession:USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
/etc/X11/Xsession:USERXSESSIONRC=$HOME/.xsessionrc
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc:if [ -r "$USERXSESSIONRC" ]; then
/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc:  . "$USERXSESSIONRC"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Debian 8.7, modifying the path in `/etc/profile` does not work for Mate Desktop.  The only thing I could get working, was to add this entry to `/etc/security/pam_env.conf` (in this case to add the TexLive binaries to PATH):

`PATH       DEFAULT=${HOME}/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin\
:/usr/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux`